# XML Schema Validation Project

Tags: xml

I have been trying to validate this XML document dealing with students and faculty and I keep on getting errors that say the element is invalid. My errors seem to be element is invalid for the most part.

I moved my attribute declarations to the top of the element declaration and I'm getting another error.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this schema to work and to validate the XML document. My XML document is well formed, along with my schema elements.

Below is my XML file, along with my 2 schema.  There are 3 documents, one regular one and 2 XML schema. I am looking to get an answer on how to fix these errors as I have tried everything I could to figure it out.  It seems like it has to do with either my attributes or my namespaces since I declare 2 namespaces in my XML document.

I have tried validating an XML document without namespaces before and I seem to do just fine with that.  I seem to have trouble with schema validation when more than one namespace is present and or I add in attributes to the mix.  Any tips on how to avoid these issues in the future would also be greatly appreciated.

### ***XML Document***

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HACC-People xmlns:s="http://www.college.com/ns/student"
                         xmlns:f="http://www.college.com/ns/faculty"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.college.com/ns/student Hacc-faculty1.xsd
                                                           http://www.college.com/ns/faculty hacc-faculty2.xsd">
  <s:student>
    <s:name first="Tyler" last="Brown">
      <s:major>Mathematics</s:major>
      <s:advisor>Norman Williams</s:advisor>
      <s:GPA>3.62</s:GPA>
      <s:phone-number>717-358-4780</s:phone-number>
    </s:name>
    <s:name first="Benny" last="Elliott">
      <s:major>Computer Science</s:major>
      <s:advisor>Amy Smith</s:advisor>
      <s:GPA>2.89</s:GPA>
      <s:phone-number>717-867-3125</s:phone-number>
    </s:name>
    <s:name first="Marcus" last="Wilt">
      <s:major>Pyschology</s:major>
      <s:advisor>Alex Schwartz</s:advisor>
      <s:GPA>3.30</s:GPA>
      <s:phone-number>717-225-4982</s:phone-number>
    </s:name>
  </s:student>
  <f:faculty>
    <f:name first="Todd" last="Anderson">
      <f:subject-taught>Web</f:subject-taught>
      <f:courses-taught>Web101, Web110, Web125</f:courses-taught>
      <f:years-teaching>5</f:years-teaching>
      <f:email>todda@hacc.edu</f:email>
      <f:phone-number>717-555-4000</f:phone-number>
    </f:name>
    <f:name first="Mark" last="Calhoun">
      <f:subject-taught>Accounting</f:subject-taught>
      <f:courses-taught>ACCT101, ACCT200, ACCT203</f:courses-taught>
      <f:years-teaching>10</f:years-teaching>
      <f:email>mjcal@hacc.edu</f:email>
      <f:phone-number>717-373-2508</f:phone-number>
    </f:name>
    <f:name first="Elizabeth" last="Hill">
      <f:subject-taught>History</f:subject-taught>
      <f:courses-taught>Hist104, Hist111</f:courses-taught>
      <f:years-teaching>3</f:years-teaching>
      <f:email>lizhill@hacc.edu</f:email>
      <f:phone-number>717-913-6942</f:phone-number>
    </f:name>
  </f:faculty>
</HACC-People>
```

### **XML Schema1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema xmlns:s="http://www.college.com/ns/student" 
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified" 
               targetNamespace="http://www.college.com/ns/student" 
               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <element name="HACC-People">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="student">
        <attribute name="first" type="string" use="required" />
        <attribute name="last" type="string" use="required" />
          <complexType>
             <sequence>
               <element name="name" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                 <complexType>
                   <sequence>
                     <element name="major" type="string" />
                     <element name="advisor" type="string" />
                     <element name="GPA" type="decimal" />
                     <element name="phone-number" type="string" />
                   </sequence>

               </complexType>
            </element>
          </sequence>
           <element ref="s:student" />
          <element ref="f:faculty" />
        </complexType>
      </element>
     </sequence>
  </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

### **XML Schema2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema xmlns:f="http://www.college.com/ns/faculty" 
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified" 
               targetNamespace="http://www.college.com/ns/faculty" 
               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <import namespace="http://www.college.com/ns/student"
          schemaLocation="Hacc-faculty1.xsd" />
  <element name="faculty">
  <attribute name="first" type="string" use="required" />
  <attribute name="last" type="string" use="required" />
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="name" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="subject-taught" type="string" />
              <element name="courses-taught" type="string" />
              <element name="years-teaching" type="integer" />
              <element name="email" type="string" />
              <element name="phone-number" type="string" />
            </sequence>

          </complexType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

Comment: There are a slew of errors -- too many to expect us to fix for you.   Take each validation error returned by a validating parser, and attempt to fix yourself.  Most error messages will be very clear, and you'll find Q/A on any that are not.  Only when you're stuck on a particular error should you post.  Dumping such a large set on us is like asking us to fix all of your compiler errors -- unreasonable.

Comment: This is very unhelpful.  I really am stuck on this and have tried for a long time to get it to validate.  I am stuck on this and am looking for a useful answer on what is wrong or a fix.  Thanks.

Comment: You've not shown where you're stuck.  I gave you the benefit of the doubt and took a couple steps toward helping you only to find that you don't need a question answered, **you need to read an introduction to XSD**.  Your *XML Schema Validation Project* "question" is not a question and is not a good fit for this site.  Read [ask].  Good luck.